# 投稿内の文章に同じ単語が重複して1と数えさせるにはSQLの構文をどう修正すればよろしいでしょうか。

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

下記コードのようにDBテーブルのbodyカラムにある「おいしい」や「まずい」など複数の文字列の合計ををBladeに表示出来ておりますが、一つの投稿に「おいしい」や「まずい」などの単語が複数あれば、複数としてカウントされてしまうようですので、DISTINCTを使い、投稿内の文章に同じ単語が重複して1と数えさせる場合、下記のようにwhereの前に書き足すかと思いましたが、文章中に「おいしい」が3回あったら3回と数えてしまいました。
お手数をおかけしますが、どう修正すればよいかご教授いただければ幸いです。よろしくお願いいたします。

Controller:

```
$posts = DB::table('Post')->select( db::raw( "body,
(LENGTH(body) - LENGTH(REPLACE(body, 'おいしい', ''))) / LENGTH('おいしい') AS cntA,
(LENGTH(body) - LENGTH(REPLACE(body, 'まずい', ''))) / LENGTH('まずい') AS cntB,
")->distinct()->where('user_id', $user)->get();
```

Blade:

```
<p>「おいしい」は全部で {{$posts->sum('cntA')}}回でした。</p>
<p>「まずい」は全部で {{$posts->sum('cntB')}}回でした。</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

「`body` に `'おいしい'` が 1 回 **以上** 含まれているレコードの数を数えたい」ということであれば `body like '%おいしい%'` の数を `sum(body like '%おいしい%')` のように数えれば良さそうです。

ただしレコードの行数や `body` の大きさによっては重い処理になることがあるので、そうなった場合は全文検索エンジンの導入など RDBMS 以外の方法での処理を考えることになりそうです。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
下記のようにコードを書いてみたのですが、いかがでしょうか。
$PostsOisiCount=Post::where('user_id', $user)->where('body', 'like', '%おいしい%')->orWhere('body', 'like', '%まずい%')->get()->count();
$PostsCount=Post::where('user_id', $user)->get()->count();
Bladeのほうで重複してもカウント１にできましたが、ユーザーAもユーザーBも投稿内容もカウントしてしまいました。またどこかでミスをしてしまったと思いますが、お手数をおかけしますが、ご教授いただますでしょうか。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: where でレコードを絞り込むのではなくて、直接 select で計算することができます。またコメントにあるコードだと user_id に対する絞り込みをしていないので全部数えられるのはそれはそうですね。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。 user_id はControllerのほうで$user=auth()->user()->id;で記述しておりますが、これで絞り込めていますでしょうか。
また、頂いたアドバイスでselectを使うイメージは下記のようなコードで合っていますでしょうか？
$posts = DB::table('Post')->select( db::raw( "body,
(LENGTH(body) - LENGTH(REPLACE(body, 'like', '%おいしい%'))) / LENGTH('おいしい') AS cntA,
(LENGTH(body) - LENGTH(REPLACE(body, 'like', '%まずい%'))) / LENGTH('まずい') AS cntB,
")->where('user_id', $user)->get();

十分理解できていなくて申し訳ないのですが、sum(body like '%おいしい%')はBladeで記述するという理解で合っていますでしょうか。

Comment: [このコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/87917/%e6%8a%95%e7%a8%bf%e5%86%85%e3%81%ae%e6%96%87%e7%ab%a0%e3%81%ab%e5%90%8c%e3%81%98%e5%8d%98%e8%aa%9e%e3%81%8c%e9%87%8d%e8%a4%87%e3%81%97%e3%81%a61%e3%81%a8%e6%95%b0%e3%81%88%e3%81%95%e3%81%9b%e3%82%8b%e3%81%ab%e3%81%afsql%e3%81%ae%e6%a7%8b%e6%96%87%e3%82%92%e3%81%a9%e3%81%86%e4%bf%ae%e6%ad%a3%e3%81%99%e3%82%8c%e3%81%b0%e3%82%88%e3%82%8d%e3%81%97%e3%81%84%e3%81%a7%e3%81%97%e3%82%87%e3%81%86%e3%81%8b/87924?noredirect=1#comment99745_87924)の書き方だと最初のクエリで user_id による絞り込みをなさっていないという指摘でした。

Comment: コメントありがとうございました。無事解決できました。ありがとうございました。